# Can access to a heroku postgresql DB be restricted to it's heroku app ONLY?

Tags: security, heroku

I've recently migrated an application from heroku to amazon-ec2 because of recomendations from a security consultant. Yet, he didn't know deeply heroku and the doubt remained.

Can access to a Heroku PostgreSQL DB be restricted for it to be accessed only by the application?

Would you recommend Heroku for security critical applications?

Comment: While not knowing Heroku, I wouldnt recommend Amazon for security critical applications - or any cloud solution for that matter! /)

Comment: My comment is based on architecture. If a third party is responsible for your customers data you can't promise who has access to it in reality.

Answer (score 7):

This is a deceptively complex question because the idea of "restricted so that it can be accessed only by the application" is ill-defined.  If your ultimate goal is simply to keep your data as secure as possible, then Heroku vs. AWS vs. physical servers under lock and key involves some cost-benefit analysis that goes beyond just how your database can be accessed.

Heroku limits database access via authentication.  You share a secret (username/password) between the database and the application.  Anyone who has that secret can access the database.  To facilitate keeping the secret secret, all database access is or should be over SSL.

There are other ways to restrict access in addition to authentication, but many of them are incompatible with a cloud-based approach.  Also, many of them require you to take much more control over the environment of your servers, and the more responsibility you have on that front, the bigger the chance that issues totally separate from who can hit the postgres port on your database will sink you.

The advantage in using AWS directly instead of through a paas provider like Heroku is that you can configure everything yourself.  The disadvantage is that you have to configure everything yourself.  I would recommend you use AWS over a managed service only if you have a team of qualified and attentive sysadmins to configure, monitor and update your environment.  Read Heroku's security policy page.  Are you doing at least that much to protect your servers in your own configuration on AWS?  If not, then you might have bigger problems than how many layers of redundancy are in place around your database.

Comment: When you say the question is "ill-defined", do you mean a) that making such a restriction would not really make the system more secure or b) that it is not possible or c) another reason altogether? I don't really see a problem in only allowing my ip/domain access to the db, while still keeping all other security measures in place. Just seems like an extra precaution that is not a bad idea?

Comment: Ill-defined means it's not clear what "only by the application" means. If you want to define it as by ip address, then that clarifies the challenge. You still have problems though: Heroku nodes are anonymous and the ip addresses will change constantly.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. If this implies "no", that would be an answer...

Comment: Even though Heroku apps changes dynamically its IP, they are between some range/s, right? I'd be nice if I can turn on/off the "external" access to DB, I'm really tired of seeing _thousands_ of messages in the logs with failed access from some hack intent.

Comment: There is a feature in beta with Heroku for IP whitelisting, but you need to request access: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#trusted-ip-ranges-for-data-services