# Can access to Heroku Postgres be restricted to an IP whitelist?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

(This is a more specific version of what was asked in [Can access to a heroku postgresql DB be restricted to it's heroku app ONLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848328/can-access-to-a-heroku-postgresql-db-be-restricted-to-its-heroku-app-only)).

We see a lot of the following in our logs:

```
sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<ip>", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

According to the [Heroku documentation](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres) this is a lazy attempt at a hack over the public internet.

Is it possible in Heroku to restrict access to an IP whitelist on top of the access control via authentication? We barely need to access our database directly and would be fine going via a static proxy whenever we do need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to restrict access by IP range or IP list.
Apparently this feature is in beta and you'll have to email a Heroku operator.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#trusted-ip-ranges-for-data-services

Comment: Inserting dummy text to satisfy a character limit is a violation of Stack Overflow's TOS (I'm an ex-offender in this regard.  ;-) ).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Russ.  I definitely didn't intend to do anything offensive.  Also, I mistakenly thought this question was restricted to a private company account.

Comment: "You can optionally choose to also allow access"... seems that this is in addition to default access, not only those whitelisted